# Gradient vector starts to increase at some point, gradient descent from scratch

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have a simple linear function y = w0 + w1 * x, where w0 and w1 are weights,
And I'm trying to implement a gradient descent for it. I wrote the function and tested in on the data(a dataset of two columns X and Y, Y is dependent on X). For the first few iterations it goes as intended, my gradient vector decreases and I expect it to reach preselected treshhold and stop there. But at some point vector starts to increase, I don't know what mistake I did in my code, please help me to find it. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
def squared_error(prediction, y):
    error = np.sum((prediction-y)**2)/len(y)
    return error

def gradient_step(x, y, prediction):
    w0_derivative = np.sum(prediction-y)
    w1_derivative = np.sum((prediction-y)*x)
    return [w0_derivative, w1_derivative]

def gradient_descent(x, y):
    errors = []
    eps = 1e-6
    step = 0.00001
    current_error = 0
    weights = np.random.rand(1,2)[0]
    L = len(x)
    t = 0
    while np.linalg.norm(weights) > eps:
        print(t, weights, np.linalg.norm(weights), current_error)
        prediction = weights[0]+weights[1]*x
        current_error = squared_error(prediction, y)
        errors.append(current_error)
        gradient = gradient_step(x, y, prediction)
        weights[0] = weights[0] - step * 2/L * gradient[0]
        weights[1] = weights[1] - step * 2/L * gradient[1]
        t+=1
    return t, weights
```

(If I can somehow hide the below output please clarify)
And here's the sample output, you can see that on iteration 38 vector norm starts to increase thus it can't reach the stopping threshold.

```
iteration:  0 weights:  [0.31865964 0.70571233] vector norm:  0.7743215427455836 current error:  0
iteration:  1 weights:  [0.3182195  0.64808332] vector norm:  0.7219942084596928 current error:  539.9063798449935
iteration:  2 weights:  [0.31792583 0.60922537] vector norm:  0.6871916691263193 current error:  261.86786860245604
iteration:  3 weights:  [0.31773094 0.58302432] vector norm:  0.6639806537564518 current error:  135.4577412755645
iteration:  4 weights:  [0.31760264 0.56535753] vector norm:  0.6484601525092629 current error:  77.98541136268015
iteration:  5 weights:  [0.31751924 0.55344519] vector norm:  0.6380595931367428 current error:  51.85562952403169
iteration:  6 weights:  [0.31746612 0.54541294] vector norm:  0.6310784575355897 current error:  39.97572738325473
iteration:  7 weights:  [0.31743342 0.53999696] vector norm:  0.6263870177268759 current error:  34.57452859878733
iteration:  8 weights:  [0.31741449 0.53634506] vector norm:  0.62323188578263 current error:  32.118870272836105
iteration:  9 weights:  [0.31740483 0.53388265] vector norm:  0.6211090962595095 current error:  31.002400996852963
iteration:  10 weights:  [0.31740144 0.53222227] vector norm:  0.6196807404591702 current error:  30.494793604390054
iteration:  11 weights:  [0.31740226 0.5311027 ] vector norm:  0.6187198631788634 current error:  30.264005077205262
iteration:  12 weights:  [0.31740593 0.53034777] vector norm:  0.6180738454010467 current error:  30.159072160707378
iteration:  13 weights:  [0.31741152 0.52983871] vector norm:  0.6176399692755613 current error:  30.11135945832206
iteration:  14 weights:  [0.3174184  0.52949544] vector norm:  0.6173490616027659 current error:  30.08966190842252
iteration:  15 weights:  [0.31742615 0.52926396] vector norm:  0.6171545204075297 current error:  30.079792139481196
iteration:  16 weights:  [0.3174345  0.52910785] vector norm:  0.6170249413446866 current error:  30.075299867461972
iteration:  17 weights:  [0.31744324 0.52900257] vector norm:  0.6169391575773583 current error:  30.073252472741405
iteration:  18 weights:  [0.31745224 0.52893155] vector norm:  0.6168829006509288 current error:  30.072316640723134
iteration:  19 weights:  [0.31746143 0.52888364] vector norm:  0.6168465514539311 current error:  30.0718861803421
iteration:  20 weights:  [0.31747074 0.52885132] vector norm:  0.6168236248664436 current error:  30.071685487019835
iteration:  21 weights:  [0.31748013 0.52882949] vector norm:  0.6168097485077322 current error:  30.071589257220854
iteration:  22 weights:  [0.31748957 0.52881476] vector norm:  0.616801974365135 current error:  30.071540521731656
iteration:  23 weights:  [0.31749906 0.52880479] vector norm:  0.6167983147497292 current error:  30.07151337951737
iteration:  24 weights:  [0.31750857 0.52879805] vector norm:  0.6167974294520366 current error:  30.07149605468038
iteration:  25 weights:  [0.31751809 0.52879348] vector norm:  0.6167984148216327 current error:  30.07148319331257
iteration:  26 weights:  [0.31752763 0.52879038] vector norm:  0.6168006615593393 current error:  30.071472361261364
iteration:  27 weights:  [0.31753717 0.52878826] vector norm:  0.616803758834994 current error:  30.071462451839917
iteration:  28 weights:  [0.31754672 0.52878681] vector norm:  0.6168074296388016 current error:  30.07145296189346
iteration:  29 weights:  [0.31755627 0.5287858 ] vector norm:  0.6168114871914999 current error:  30.07144366266287
iteration:  30 weights:  [0.31756583 0.5287851 ] vector norm:  0.6168158055533827 current error:  30.07143445014285
iteration:  31 weights:  [0.31757539 0.5287846 ] vector norm:  0.6168202998069839 current error:  30.07142527704745
iteration:  32 weights:  [0.31758494 0.52878424] vector norm:  0.6168249126949067 current error:  30.071416121878023
iteration:  33 weights:  [0.3175945  0.52878398] vector norm:  0.6168296056101267 current error:  30.071406974860405
iteration:  34 weights:  [0.31760406 0.52878377] vector norm:  0.6168343525210258 current error:  30.071397831550584
iteration:  35 weights:  [0.31761362 0.52878361] vector norm:  0.6168391358752219 current error:  30.071388689928252
iteration:  36 weights:  [0.31762318 0.52878348] vector norm:  0.6168439438376392 current error:  30.071379549074727
iteration:  37 weights:  [0.31763274 0.52878336] vector norm:  0.61684876842822 current error:  30.0713704085725
iteration:  38 weights:  [0.3176423  0.52878326] vector norm:  0.6168536042662351 current error:  30.071361268231524
iteration:  39 weights:  [0.31765186 0.52878317] vector norm:  0.6168584477236104 current error:  30.071352127965643
iteration:  40 weights:  [0.31766142 0.52878308] vector norm:  0.6168632963540365 current error:  30.071342987735534
iteration:  41 weights:  [0.31767098 0.528783  ] vector norm:  0.6168681485080346 current error:  30.07133384752333
iteration:  42 weights:  [0.31768054 0.52878292] vector norm:  0.6168730030734078 current error:  30.07132470732093
iteration:  43 weights:  [0.3176901  0.52878284] vector norm:  0.6168778593002311 current error:  30.071315567124664
iteration:  44 weights:  [0.31769966 0.52878276] vector norm:  0.6168827166828511 current error:  30.07130642693288
iteration:  45 weights:  [0.31770922 0.52878269] vector norm:  0.6168875748803186 current error:  30.071297286744738
iteration:  46 weights:  [0.31771878 0.52878261] vector norm:  0.6168924336627406 current error:  30.071288146559965
iteration:  47 weights:  [0.31772834 0.52878254] vector norm:  0.6168972928751059 current error:  30.07127900637834
iteration:  48 weights:  [0.3177379  0.52878246] vector norm:  0.6169021524128935 current error:  30.071269866199884
iteration:  49 weights:  [0.31774746 0.52878239] vector norm:  0.6169070122056274 current error:  30.071260726024477
iteration:  50 weights:  [0.31775702 0.52878231] vector norm:  0.6169118722057866 current error:  30.071251585852142
iteration:  51 weights:  [0.31776658 0.52878224] vector norm:  0.616916732381328 current error:  30.071242445682856
iteration:  52 weights:  [0.31777614 0.52878216] vector norm:  0.6169215927106454 current error:  30.07123330551661
iteration:  53 weights:  [0.3177857  0.52878209] vector norm:  0.6169264531791692 current error:  30.071224165353485
iteration:  54 weights:  [0.31779526 0.52878201] vector norm:  0.6169313137770746 current error:  30.071215025193343
iteration:  55 weights:  [0.31780482 0.52878194] vector norm:  0.6169361744977363 current error:  30.0712058850363
iteration:  56 weights:  [0.31781438 0.52878186] vector norm:  0.6169410353366862 current error:  30.071196744882265
iteration:  57 weights:  [0.31782394 0.52878179] vector norm:  0.6169458962909106 current error:  30.0711876047313
iteration:  58 weights:  [0.3178335  0.52878171] vector norm:  0.6169507573583767 current error:  30.07117846458336
iteration:  59 weights:  [0.31784306 0.52878164] vector norm:  0.6169556185377126 current error:  30.07116932443854
iteration:  60 weights:  [0.31785262 0.52878157] vector norm:  0.6169604798279933 current error:  30.071160184296716
iteration:  61 weights:  [0.31786218 0.52878149] vector norm:  0.6169653412285931 current error:  30.071151044158
iteration:  62 weights:  [0.31787174 0.52878142] vector norm:  0.6169702027390902 current error:  30.071141904022262
iteration:  63 weights:  [0.3178813  0.52878134] vector norm:  0.6169750643591987 current error:  30.071132763889636
iteration:  64 weights:  [0.31789086 0.52878127] vector norm:  0.6169799260887253 current error:  30.071123623760045
iteration:  65 weights:  [0.31790042 0.52878119] vector norm:  0.6169847879275386 current error:  30.071114483633497
iteration:  66 weights:  [0.31790998 0.52878112] vector norm:  0.6169896498755493 current error:  30.071105343510006
iteration:  67 weights:  [0.31791954 0.52878104] vector norm:  0.6169945119326963 current error:  30.07109620338955
iteration:  68 weights:  [0.3179291  0.52878097] vector norm:  0.6169993740989372 current error:  30.071087063272184
iteration:  69 weights:  [0.31793866 0.52878089] vector norm:  0.6170042363742433 current error:  30.071077923157834
iteration:  70 weights:  [0.31794822 0.52878082] vector norm:  0.6170090987585936 current error:  30.07106878304657
```

Comment: I see that the prediction error goes down. Why do you expect the norm of the weights to become smaller, as they depend on the nature of the data? Your prediction is y = w[0] + w[1] * x, why do you expect them to become smaller than eps? E.g. you may have a true value as y = 1 + 5*x, the norm of w would never become smaller than eps.

Comment: @piplustwo The nature of the data is linear, I declare that based on exploratory analysis. There's a strong correlation between X and Y. Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I thought that my implementation of the algorithm will find the optimal weights when the norm will reach the value of 1e-6, meaning that our gradient reached value which is close enough to zero. For now my code won't stop running, however the error goes down.

Comment: Yes, but why do you expect the norm of the weights to become small?

Comment: You are confusing the weight with the delta weight. You have to set the convergence on the delta weight, not the weight itself.

Comment: Yes, my assumption about norm of the weights to become small was wrong. By delta weight, do you mean delta between current weight and the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the delta weight, not the weight itself.

```
def gradient_descent(x, y):
    errors = []
    eps = 1e-7
    step = 0.001
    current_error = 0
    weights = np.random.rand(1,2)[0]
    new_weights = np.zeros(2)
    delta_weights = weights.copy()
    L = len(x)
    t = 0
    while np.linalg.norm(delta_weights) > eps:
        # if t > 40:
        #     break
        print(t, weights, np.linalg.norm(delta_weights), current_error)
        prediction = weights[0]+weights[1]*x
        current_error = squared_error(prediction, y)
        errors.append(current_error)
        gradient = gradient_step(x, y, prediction)
        new_weights[0] = weights[0] - step * 2/L * gradient[0]
        new_weights[1] = weights[1] - step * 2/L * gradient[1]
        delta_weights[0] = new_weights[0] - weights[0]
        delta_weights[1] = new_weights[1] - weights[1]
        weights[0] = new_weights[0]
        weights[1] = new_weights[1]
        t+=1
    return t, weights



x = np.random.randn(100) * 5
y = 2 + 3 * x + np.random.randn(100)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()

gradient_descent(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I set the break condition as delta_weights < eps, I think that's enough to compute optimal weights.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reduce the gradient by some order of magnitude. I tried on `x = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.74), y = 1.8*x + 2.1` your code and the error is less than 1.

Comment: But what should we take as the order of magnitude?

Comment: Try with 0.0000001, make then some experiments to check which order of magnitude fits best

Comment: I will try that, thank you!